# Symbology and statistic issues with interpolation maps in Geostatistical Wizard of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, kriging, geostatistical-analyst

I have created a series of depth interpolation maps using ordinary kriging with the Geostatistical Wizard in ArcGIS Pro. To make the maps comparable to each other, I manually adjusted the class breaks and color scheme to 10 individual class breaks, 10cm each, from 0 to 100cm. I want to calculate percentage of area of each map within each class break and think I need to convert the modeled map to a raster first in order to do so, but the symbology never carries over. Further, when I try to manually adjust the symbology into the 10 class breaks again once exported as a raster, it is impossible to make manual class breaks for a map which data range doesn't extend to the class break I am making (for example, in a map with predicted values ranging from 97-100 cm, I cannot create manual class breaks from 0-10, 10-20, 20-30, etc. until 97.)

Could I be doing these statistics without exporting as a raster and losing the manual class breaks and symbology?